# DSPATR(PR) in RPG program to protect the field

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I'm developing RPG program on the IBM developing software

what happen is that I'm creating a display file with input field

I'm trying to accomplish one task.

If they already input all the field and the other record is display I want to protect the filed that they just input the value until they press enter

but I'm confuse how can I use the  DSPATR(PR) to protect the field

Comment: So once the user has keyed data into the fields, you want to redisplay the screen with (perhaps certain) fields protected.  Usually when we redisplay a screen for confirmation, we want to allow the user to make any corrections that might be appropriate.  In this case you do not want them to be able to correct a mistake?

Comment: @WarrenT well this is the requirement for the program that I've to write to protect the field information incase they want to change they can just press enter to unprotect the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for my question.

To do this just go to properties on the screen designer > right click to properties and find keyword `protect` and this will protect the whole screen for the field that they enter until `enter` is pressed to unprotect.

It's also can be done by adding `DSPATR(PR)` with indicator and add this to `RPG` to turn on the indicator for the required field.

Answer (score 2):

On the green-screen the RPG program only knows about what is on the screen when you hit `<enter>` on your screen. It sounds like you want to protect a field after the user has entered data into the field. I don't think that is possible unless each field has the `CHECK(ER)` on each field. That would get annoying depending on the program function. Hands-down entry people prefer to just keep typing and they have memorized exactly how many tabs and spaces they need to key to enter the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found the solution for that and it's possible in RPG with the screen designer [DSP]

Answer (score 0):

For study purpouse you can set display attributes since your RPG "backend" code, for example in your case the hexadecimal code value for protect (read only) filed is 'A0', take a look of the code:

In DDSSRC:

```
.....AAN01N02N03T.Nombre++++RLon++TPdBLínPosFunciones+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 A* First declare the variable 
 A                REV1           1A  P
 A*
 A* then, after the display field in function limit you assign it
 A*
 A                FIELD01       14Y 2B 17 42EDTCDE(1)    
 A                                          DSPATR(&REV1)
```

In RPGSRC, just set or clear when you need it:

```
CL0N01Factor1+++++++Operac&ExtFactor2+++++++Resultado+++++Lon++D+MaMeIg....Comentarios+++++++++
C* 
C* Set the hex value in the QDDSSRC variable
C                       EVAL      REV2 = x'A0'
C*
C* Clear the variable
C                   CLEAR                   REV1              1
```

There are too many hexa codes for many purpouses, just need to look around the www :).

Answer (score -1):

A            SEL            1A  B 11  2
 A  99                                  DSPATR(PC)

### A  99                                  DSPATR(RI)

When you display a field on the green screen, you EXFMT generally for I/O.
Here, I would clear the SEL field first then EXFMT the record format from the display(DDS) file.   Once the user presses ENTER, I "turn on" the indicator 99.
I would then EXFMT  again to display the screen.  In the example if *IN99 was *ON, the cursor would Position To the SEL field AND Reverse Image it.  You can do the same with protect DSPATR(PR).   In your code, you'd "set off" the indicator, display the screen. User hits ENTER you "turn on" the indicator and repop the screen.

In RPG, you can use  MOVE *ON  *IN99.

or you can use  SETON ........99.

or MOVE '1'   *IN99.

In CLP, you can    CHGVAR VAR(&IN99) VALUE('1')